# How to copy a whole directory recursively with an npm script on Windows 10 Powershell?

Tags: npm-scripts

### How to copy a whole directory recursively with an npm script on Windows 10 Powershell?

Right now I have the following tree:

```
test
├───1
│       package.json
│
└───2
    └───src
        │   asd.txt
        │
        └───asd
                asd - Copy (2).txt
                asd - Copy.txt
                asd.txt
```

What I want is a script that when run in dir `1` it goes to dir `2` and copies the whole dir `src` recursively from there to dir `1`. So in the end I would have a similar `src` in `1` as there is in `2`.

When I `cd` to the directory `1` and run `npm run build:ui` which is defined in `package.json` as

```json
"scripts": {
    "build:ui": "cd ..\\2 && copy src ..\\1"
}
```

it starts doing kind of what I want but not quite; it copies stuff from directory `2` to `1`. The problem is it doesn't copy the whole directory with all of its subdirectories and all the possible contents, instead it just copies the files from directly inside `2/src/`. In other words, here's what the tree looks like after the operation:

```
test
├───1
│       asd.txt
│       package.json
│
└───2
    └───src
        │   asd.txt
        │
        └───asd
                asd - Copy (2).txt
                asd - Copy.txt
                asd.txt
```

So only the file `asd.txt` got copied.

Other configurations I have tried without success include:

```json
"scripts": {
    "build:ui": "cd ..\\2 && copy -r src ..\\1"
}
```

```json
"scripts": {
    "build:ui": "cd ..\\2 && Copy-Item -Recursive src ..\\1"
}
```

```json
"scripts": {
    "build:ui": "cd ..\\2 && cp -r src ..\\1"
}
```

...none of which are even valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider utilizing the [`xcopy`](https://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html) command instead of [`copy`](https://ss64.com/nt/copy.html) as it better suits your requirement.

Redefine your `build:ui` script in the `scripts` section of your *package.json* file as follows:

**Scripts section of package.json:**

```json
"scripts": {
  "build:ui": "xcopy /e/h/y/q \"../2/src\" \"./src\\\" > nul 2>&1"
}
```

**Running:**

When you `cd` to the directory named `1`, (i.e. the directory that contains the *package.json* with the aforementioned `build:ui` script defined in it), and then run:

```
npm run build:ui
```

it will produce the resultant directory structure:

```
test
├── 1
│   ├── package.json
│   └── src
│       ├── asd
│       │   ├── asd - Copy (2).txt
│       │   ├── asd - Copy.txt
│       │   └── asd.txt
│       └── asd.txt
└── 2
    └── src
        ├── asd
        │   ├── asd - Copy (2).txt
        │   ├── asd - Copy.txt
        │   └── asd.txt
        └── asd.txt
```

As you can see, the `src` folder inside folder `2`, and all of it's contents, has been copied to folder `1`.

---

#### Explanation:

The following provides a detailed breakdown of the aforementioned `xcopy` command:

**Options:**

- `/e` - Copy folders and subfolders, including empty folders.
- `/h` - Copy hidden and system files and folders.
- `/y` - Suppress prompt to confirm overwriting a file.
- `/q` - Do not display file names while copying.

**Notes:**

- Each pathname has been encased in JSON escaped double quotes, i.e. `\"...\"`
- The `./src\\` part has a trailing backslash (`\`), which has been JSON escaped (`\\`), to inform `xcopy` that the destination is a directory. This also ensures the `src` directory is created if it doesn't already exist.
- The `> nul 2>&1` part suppresses the confirmation log that states how many files were copied.

---

#### Related information:

It's worth noting that on Windows npm utilizes `cmd.exe` as the default shell for running npm scripts - regardless of the CLI tool you're using, e.g. *PowerShell*. You can verify this by utilizing the [npm-config](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/config) command to check the [script-shell](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#script-shell) setting. For instance run the following command:

```
npm config get script-shell
```

---

#### Edit:

If you want your resultant directory structure to be like this:

```
test
├── 1
│   ├── asd
│   │   ├── asd - Copy (2).txt
│   │   ├── asd - Copy.txt
│   │   └── asd.txt
│   ├── asd.txt
│   └── package.json
└── 2
    └── src
        ├── asd
        │   ├── asd - Copy (2).txt
        │   ├── asd - Copy.txt
        │   └── asd.txt
        └── asd.txt
```

This time the contents of the `src` folder inside the folder named `2` has been copied to folder `1` - but not the actual containing `src` folder itself.

Then you need to define your npm script as follows:

```json
"scripts": {
  "build:ui": "xcopy /e/h/y/q \"../2/src\" \".\" > nul 2>&1"
}
```

<sub>**Note:** the destination path has been changed from `\"./src\\\"` to `\".\"`.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

**For something like this, I might use an approach similar to the below.**

Modify your NPM script (`build:ui`) to call a Powershell script(`build.ui.ps1`) that is located in the same dir as the package.json file.

```
"scripts": {
    "build:ui": "@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ./build.ui.ps1"
},
```

Create the aforementioned Powershell script with the following contents.

```bsh
param(
    $srcParentDir = '2',
    $srcDir = 'src',
    $srcDestDir = '1'
)

Set-Location (get-item $PSScriptRoot).parent.FullName
Copy-Item -Path "$srcParentDir\$srcDir" -Destination $srcDestDir -Recurse
```

Run the npm script
`npm run build:ui`