# use xcopy in package.json

Tags: package.json, xcopy

I have a react application and a express server. I am serving react app through express server as a static page. I want to copy the build folder from the react application to server each time I build the react project. I am using xcopy, but its not working.

```json
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build && xcopy C:\Users\gevi\Scheduler\client\build C:\Users\gevi\Scheduler\Server\build /E/H/C/I",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example is [not valid JSON](https://jsonlint.com/?code=), therefore consider making the following changes:

- Escape the backslashes, i.e. change all `\` to `\\`
- Encase the pathnames in JSON escaped double quotes (i.e. `\"...\"`).

Essentially, redefine your `build` script as follows:

```json
"scripts": {
  ...
  "build": "react-scripts build && xcopy \"C:\\Users\\gevi\\Scheduler\\client\\build\" \"C:\\Users\\gevi\\Scheduler\\Server\\build\" /E/H/C/I",
  ...
}
```

For clarity purposes the following example uses a circumflex (`^`) character to indicate each additional change made to the `build` script (as per above) that you provided in your question:

```json
"build": "react-scripts build && xcopy \"C:\\Users\\gevi\\Scheduler\\client\\build\" \"C:\\Users\\gevi\\Scheduler\\Server\\build\" /E/H/C/I",
                                       ^^  ^      ^     ^          ^       ^      ^^ ^^  ^      ^     ^          ^       ^      ^^
```

Please refer to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61539374/how-to-copy-a-whole-directory-recursively-with-an-npm-script-on-windows-10-power/61561003#61561003) if you need to change the `xcopy` options. E.g.

- You may want to add the [`/Q`](http://www.embeddedframeworks.com/cmds/nt/xcopy.html) option to not display file names in the console while copying.
- Or, maybe add an escaped backlash at the end of the destination path to ensure that the `build` folder is created if it doesn't already exist on the server. If that's a requirement then change the destination path in the previous example to:

  ```json
  \"C:\\Users\\gevi\\Scheduler\\Server\\build\\\"
                                             ^^
  ```